# How Can I Query a Pdf Reader If It's On The Last Page?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, pdf, pdf-reader

I'm writing a wrapper shell-script to do the following:

1. Searches a directory for .pdf/.djv files.
2. makes an ordered "playlist" of files
3. Opens 1st file in a pdf reader.
4. Automatically change to the next page every 0.5/1.0/2.0s (user configurable)
5. **When a .pdf/.djvu reaches its end, the next pdf is loaded from the "playlist"** and so on till the "playlist" gets exhausted.

Assuming that I don't have access to the source-code of the Pdf Reader, how would the script know it's come to the end of the .pdf?

Comment: It sounds like you got everything else under control so ... (1) read current page number; (2) "automatically change to the next page"; (3) read current page number. If it's the same, you reached the end.

Comment: Actually, nothing has actually been code (or should I say scripted) yet, but as far as I've read on forums, there are small programs that can (as it seems to me) automate (1),(2) and (3) easily. For (4) I'll be using xdtools to insert KEY_SPACE. The tools that I'm aware of can't "read current page number". Since, I sensed a kind of sarcasm in your reply, I wish to tell you I'm not a programmer by any means. I'm a Research Scholar in Neurosciences and need this thing to work for a research project in human cognition and learning. So please be kind to me.

Comment: All shell scripts can only work by dint of whatever means the software *exposes*. So, while you are right on 1-3, from that point on you are at the mercy of your PDF reader. If sending keys work but you get no feedback, try finding a command line utility that can return the number of pages in a PDF. Then you could (possibly) insert that number in the page turning loop. (It *sounds* as this should be possible, but that's about it for me and `bash`.)

Answer (score 0):

```
            DELAY=3
            loc="/2/Downloads/"
            find "$loc"* -type f | sort -h|egrep 'djvu|pdf$'>.delete;
            n=`wc -l <.delete`
            while [ "$n" -gt 0 ];
            do
            if [ -f pagenumber ] 
            then 
            i=`more pagenumber` # you can maniupulate it to make a filename which can store individual pagenumber inisilization ;)
            else 
            i=0;
            fi
            a=$(pdftk "`tail -"$n" .delete | head -1`" dump_data|more|egrep -i numberofpages|egrep -io '[0-9]*')
            while [ $i -lt $a ] ; 
            do 
            evince -i "$i" "`tail -"$n" .delete | head -1`" & sleep "$DELAY"s;i=$(($i+1));echo page number $i;
            echo $i > pagenumber
            done  || gnome-open "`tail -"$n" .delete | head -1`"
            sleep 10s
            rm pagenumber
            n=$(($n-1))
            done
```

Comment: I didn't know one could query evince so easily. I presume this works for other pdf readers as well- esp. Okular. Okular too is DBUS compatible. PS.- I'm not a programmer; but, I love to learn. :)

Comment: @ user3975793 Since we're doing this as part of a research project, we'd like to "credit" you for the script in our research-paper. Kindly revert.

Comment: As you might have learned from my previous posts, I'm associated with a Neuroscience research project (Human Cognition and Learning) at NIMHANS, India (http://www.nimhans.kar.nic.in/). Kindly send us information as to how we should 'identify' you in our research-paper at akiesresearch-at-gmail-dot-com. Moreover, we'd like to know if you'd be willing to write such scripts for our project in the future as well (like, for eg. if we want 16 instances of the same/similar/forked pdf reader to get diplayed similarly, what changes should we make to the script) as we're not IT/CSE Univ. Thanks

Comment: Sorry i did not come login to this site for so long.Please Check ur mail.thanks and Yes i will be willing to do that very happily :D